# Testing Akka. Check that JavaTestKit probe received PoisonPill message

Tags: java, scala, testing, akka

I test my actor system and I need to verify that actor sends PoisonPill message in some scenario. I mock target actor with JavaTestKit probe and try to check that it receives PoisonPill. But it doesn't work:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
JavaTestKit probe = new JavaTestKit(system);
probe.getRef().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender());
Object o = probe.expectMsgClass(FiniteDuration.apply(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), Object.class);
//here we get exception
```

Is there any way to check that probe is terminated?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify if `PoisonPill` has been received by asserting behavior associated with that - actor, which received poison pill, will automatically stop. To track actor termination, you can use `probe.watch(target)` and then `probe.expectMsgClass(Terminated.class)` to verify if actor has been terminated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Horusiath Thanks for you response.
So I have to create one more probe for testing such behavior:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("x");
ActorRef victim = TestProbe.apply(system).ref();
TestProbe probe = TestProbe.apply(system);
probe.watch(victim);
ActorRef killer = system.actorOf(Props.create(Killer.class, victim));
killer.tell("kill!", ActorRef.noSender());
probe.expectMsgClass(Terminated.class);
```